# Phew! Etymology

Tags: etymology

I'm interested in the etymology of the expression *"phew"*.

My online chambers dictionary says it's *"a half-formed whistle"*. This leaves more questions than it answers, such as *"why a half-formed whistle?"* (as if I have a feeling of 'disgust, exhaustion, surprise, impatience, relief' I'm not tempted to whistle or half whistle) and *"why is it spelt with a 'ph' rather than the more obvious 'f'?"*.

[Various](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phew) [sources](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/08/on-the-scent.html) say the word originates from c.1600. I perhaps naively thought that words with 'ph' in them were in general imports from other languages (e.g. greek) where a 'phi' like letter existed.

So where does *'phew'* come from?

Comment: The *'ph'* is to differentiate onomatopoeia from a regular word.

Comment: @54696D taking a random list (https://kathytemean.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/onomatopoeia-word-list/) as a sample, 'phew' is the only onomatopoeic word with a 'ph', so it can hardly be a popular change. Why not (e.g.) 'fyoo'?

Comment: My question: did *whew* represent the same whistle as *phew*?

Comment: @abligh To me, it seems that *'fyoo'* would be a odd spelling considering there aren't many words that start with *'fy'*.  And most words with a *'yoo'* sound are simply spelled with the letter u.

Comment: Both *phew* and *whew* are onomatopoeic words that imitate the sound of expiration/exhalation, especially a subdued expiration.

Comment: @Drew *'whew'* somehow makes a lot more sense, particularly in the context of *'whistle'*.

Comment: Do not confuse *phew* with *P.U.*. The former is pronounced with a *f* sound, and the meanings are completely different.

Comment: @54696D are there *any* other onomatapoeia with a 'ph'?

Comment: What do you mean by *makes a lot more sense*? Expire with an *f* sound. Now expire with a *wh* sound. You can expire both ways, and they are different.

Comment: @abligh No, not that I can think of.

Comment: Sure - *phooey* is another with *ph*. There are in fact lots of these, which are borderline onomatapoeic and euphemisms for *f* words: *fudge*, *fricking*, *freaking*, *fiddlesticks*,... Whether and how much a given one is  onomatapoeic is an open question. I'm guessing that *phooey* is, to some extent.

Comment: @Drew I meant that if the origin was a 'half-whistle' as per Chambers, characterising the sound as *'whew'* makes more sense to me, as whistles do not (to me) seem to start with an 'f' sound, and the extra 'aspiration' noise (not sure if that's a real term) indicated by the 'h' makes sense after a w, in a way that a 'f'/'ph' distinction does not. But then I'm no expert on pronunciation, linguistics or etymology (hence the question).

Comment: @Drew *'phooey'* seems to come from the Yiddish *'pfui'* which presumably explains its 'p'. Of course *'pfui'* might be onomatapoeic originally.

Comment: When I vocalize "phew", my lips come together almost like saying "pew", but not quite. The sound is in between "few" or "whew", but feels like a half-formed "pew".

Comment: It's the sound that comes first. It's not vocalized, but neither is a whistle. What it is is a low-velocity whistle without a sharply-defined vibration site. The spelling is not official, since it's an interjection and not a real word; it's meant to imitate the sound, i.e, there is no etymology. The /f/ and /u/ are because the lips are rounded and closely spaced; in fact the /f/ is a bilabial fricative [ɸ], not labiodental [f] like it normally is. The /i/ represents the tongue's movement upward toward the final /u/, compressing the air.

Comment: The word "phew" is imitative of a long,exasperated,exhausted exhalation,also suggesting the appreciated end of a strenuous,laborious task.If there was still more to do, instead of vocalizing a "phew",an inhalation would occur.

Comment: Don't you think a fully-formed whistle generally shows approval, so one half-formed might indicate something similar?

Doesn't "phew" generally show relief or salutation, which might very well be half way to approval?

Answer (score 2):

I would surmise that it came from an exaggerated sigh. When one is sighing out of boredom, frustration, and the like, one might take a deep breath and release the air through the side of one’s mouth in a puff-making a noise that, to my ear, sounds like a *pew* or *phew*.  I’m guessing that *phew* is the official word for that utterance.

Comment: Well, there ain't no "official" word, but "phew" is as good a spelling as any for the sound that is quite natural to make and has it's origin in the human body/brain, not any ancient language.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's the sound that comes first. It's not vocalized, but neither is a whistle. What it is is a low-velocity whistle without a sharply-defined vibration site. The spelling is not official, since it's an interjection and not a real word; it's meant to imitate the sound, i.e, there is no etymology. The /f/ and /u/ are because the lips are rounded and closely spaced; in fact the /f/ is a bilabial fricative [ɸ], not labiodental [f] like it normally is. The /i/ represents the tongue's movement upward toward the final /u/, compressing the air.

Answer (score 0):

As language goes it's akin to an ancient day emoji. An expressive onomatopoeia that has no real purpose other than to emphasise to others the emotion that may otherwise have been held in the body/mind. Phew to my mind is an expression of relief.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).